# asp.net web deployment and hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I m very new to Asp.net technology. I have created website in asp.net and created package for it and hosted in local iis.
 After hosting I made some changes in website in code behind and now I wanted it to be hosted in iis but I don't want to repeat all the stuff for hosting. does it work well if I paste built package on wwwroot folder?
please help

Comment: I assume when u say `IIS` u mean deployment server, most of your configs are stored in the `web.config` so that would make sure they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is exactly what Web Deploy does. Just make sure to compile your code and get them from \bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can xcopy DLLs into the host folder and it should just work. IIS should pick up the changes right away.